# ActiveModel::Serializer: Recommended way to use with join table (has_many through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I'm facing a case when a need to display information contained in my join table. For example:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: quality_inspections
#
#  id, content
#
# =============================================================================

class QualityInspection
  has_many :inspection_inspectors
  has_many :inspector, through: :inspection_inspectors
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: inspection_inspectors
#
#  quality_inspection_id, inspector_id, inspection_date
#
# =============================================================================

class InspectionInspector
  belongs_to :quality_inspection
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :inspector_id
end
```

Then, I'd like to have the following json:

```
{
  "quality_inspectors": [{
    "id": 1,
    "content": "foo",
    "inspectors": [{
      "id": 1, // which is the user's id
      "first_name": "Bar",
      "last_name": "FooFoo",
      "inspection_date": "random date"
    }]
  }]
}
```

For now, I'm doing the following in my serializer:

```
module Api::V1::QualityInspections
  class InspectorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    type :inspector

    attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :inspection_date

    def id
      inspector.try(:public_send, __callee__)
    end

    def first_name
      inspector.try(:public_send, __callee__)
    end

    def last_name
      inspector.try(:public_send, __callee__)
    end

    private

    def inspector
      @inspector ||= object.inspector
    end
  end
end
```

Do you have any better solution ? Or maybe I'm not using the right methods on my Serializer ?

Anyway, I'm really stuck when it came to display information on a join table. Oddly, I'd the same issue when using cerebris/jsonapi-resources.

EDIT: Linked issue on GH: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1704

Comment: I think you can just add association on serializer like added in mode it will return proper json to you

Comment: @Ansar if I has `has_many :inspectors`, I'll end with a nested resource.

Comment: @cappie013 Would you mind linking to the corresponding issue on GH for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to put additional methods such as id, first_name, last_name. Instead, use association within your serializer to get the appropriate JSON data as mentioned afore.